# Saving to parquet subpartition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a directory structure based on two partitions, like this:

```
  People
  > surname=Doe
        > name=John
        > name=Joe
  > surname=White
        > name=Josh
        > name=Julien
```

I am reading parquet files with information only about all Does, and therefore I am **directly** specifying surname=Doe as an output directory for my DataFrame. Now the problem is I am trying to add name-based partitioning with `partitionBy("name")` on writing.

```
df.write.partitionBy("name").parquet(outputDir)
```

(outputDir contains a path to Doe directory)

This causes an error like below:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting partition column names detected:
    Partition column name list #0: surname, name
    Partition column name list #1: surname
```

Any tips how to solve it? It probably occurs because of the `_SUCCESS` file created in the surname directory, which gives wrong hints to Spark - when I remove `_SUCCESS` and `_metadata` files Spark is able to read everything without any issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have managed to solve it with a workaround - I don't think this is a good idea, but I disabled creating additional _SUCCESS and _metadata files with:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
```

That way Spark won't get any stupid ideas about the partitioning structures.

Another option is saving to the "proper" directory - People and partition by surname and name, but then you have to keep in mind that the only sane option is setting `SaveMode` to `Append` and manually deleting the directories you expect to be overwritten (this is **really** error-prone):

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("surname","name").parquet("/People")
```

Do not use owerwrite SaveMode in this case - this will delete ALL of the surname directores.

Comment: Since noone else posted and my bounty expires, I am accepting this solution as the only one known for now.

Comment: This worked for me for Spark 1.6.3 `sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")`

Answer (score 2):

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
```

is fairly sensible, if you have summary metadata enabled then writing the metadata file can become an IO bottleneck on reads and writes.

The alternative way to your solution might be to add a .mode("append") to your write, but with the original parent directory as the destination,

```
df.write.mode("append").partitionBy("name").parquet("/People")
```

Comment: The problem with append is I would have to manually delete the data, which will be bothersome in my case.

Comment: True, but then deleting file partitions in Spark is rudimentary at best anyway...